# Issue: Horizontal scrolling effect with Skrollr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I want to create an horizontal animation controlled by the skrollr.
Scrolling down, the elements of my page have to move from left to right of my container.

Assuming that my elements have all the same width, I set the scrolling data from 100% to 0% and it works.

But what if my images have different widths? 
Also I want to preserve the opacity animation that create this fade-in fade-out effect.

Here's HTML code:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="bg" style="background-color:red" 
        data-0="transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0); opacity:1"  
        data-5000="transform:translate3d(-100%,0%,0); opacity:0">
    </div>

    <div class="bg" style="background-color:green;" 
        data-0="transform:translate3d(100%,0%,0); opacity:0"    
        data-5000="transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0);opacity:1"
        data-10000="transform:translate3d(-100%,0%,0);opacity:0">
    </div>

    <div class="bg" style="background-color:orange" 
        data-5000="transform:translate3d(100%,0%,0); opacity:0"     
        data-10000="transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0); opacity:1">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#container {
    background-color:black;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div {
    position:fixed;
}
.bg {
    width:500px; 
    height:300px; 
}
```

#### [Here's a Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvLtwcjc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just set the widths to 100% and contain your images within:

```css
#container {
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;   
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div {
   position:fixed;
}
.bg {
    width:100%; 
    height:300px; 
}
```

#### [Here's a Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/09wyzte5/)

Comment: I'm referring to different widths between the elements like that: http://jsfiddle.net/09wyzte5/1/

Comment: its better if you add some images to get and idea what you want. im under the impression you want to contain the widths.

Comment: If one of my element have a different width that element will not placed after it's previous but overlaid to it, loosing the slideshow effect that I'm searching for. http://jsfiddle.net/09wyzte5/3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the different width would be a problem. You could set all width to 100% and overflow: hidden; or use jQuery to check the best way to fit the image in the container.

Comment: If one of my element have a different width that element will not placed after it's previous but overlaid to it, loosing the slideshow effect that I'm searching for. http://jsfiddle.net/09wyzte5/1/

Comment: Not if they all have width 100%. Then they will fill the container.

Comment: The problem is that the skrollr interpolation see the 100% of the width of  each div and place it not after the previous div but overlaid to it as you can see here. http://jsfiddle.net/09wyzte5/5/

Comment: Why are you using a vertical scrollbar for horizontal scrolling? Sorry just realized this.

Comment: personal choice. I would like to realize the animation in this way.

Comment: It would be vary easy to do this with a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I know Marcel but I like to complicate my life :) I'm searching for the solution but I really can't. Can you see the solution for this? Thanks for your consideration.