# How to do horizontal parallax scrolling

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, parallax, skrollr

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap, JQuery, and Skrollr.

I would like to have a static background and a couple scenes that occur as you scroll by parallax scrolling.  I'm able to make scenes as you scroll but I'm looking for a way to where it appears that you are not moving down the page.

I'm looking to make a scene like this image:

[image: example]

Notice how it moves right-left but never appears like you are actually scrolling down the page.

That's the best I can explain it.  Can't seem to find any good tutorials to accomplish this.  Any help in the right direction would be outstanding.

Comment: How about `parallax horizontal scrolling` or `parallax sideways scrolling`

Comment: Thanks @Adimeus.  Are you saying to use a different script than skrollr?  Or guiding me in my google searches?  Thanks again

Comment: From the author of skrollr: `skrollr does not support horizontal scrolling websites and never will. Horizontal scrolling is the worst invention ever. Neither mouse wheel nor page up/down keys are working for horizontal scrolling.` - [Prinzhorn](http://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/47)

Comment: Ahh, thank you!  I'll do some looking into horizontal scrolling then.  Appreciate your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, horizontal scrolling isn't supported by skrollr, but you can do something else:

You can use the vertical scrollbar to animate elements in a horizontally.

Here's a Stack Overflow post on [**Horizontal scrolling effect with Skrollr**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289028/issue-horizontal-scrolling-effect-with-skrollr)
And here's a working demo in [**jsFiddle from that post**](http://jsfiddle.net/09wyzte5/)

Hope this gets you going.

Comment: I was just about to comment that horizontal scrolling isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  But, THIS is!  Thanks for the help and thanks everyone else too!!  Appreciate you!

Answer (score 1):

[jInvertScroll](https://github.com/pixxelfactory/jInvertScroll) allows for horizontal scrolling and supports parallax.

Here's an article on how to [create horizontal parallax scrolling with jInvertScroll](http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/create-horizontal-parallax-scrolling-with-jinvertscroll/)

Just use different values for horizon and middle scroll

```html
<div class="horizon scroll">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IImTBHM.png" alt="Background" />
</div>

<div class="middle scroll">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2pwKbv.png" alt="Clouds and Baloons" />
</div>
```

**Here's a demo in stack snippets**:

> **Note**: Try viewing in **full page**

```js
(function($) {
  $.jInvertScroll(['.scroll']);
}(jQuery));
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  background: #9fdefd;
}
h1, h2 {
  color: #238acb;
}
.horizon {
  line-height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 3000px;
}
.middle {
  line-height: 0;
  z-index: 250;
  width: 4500px;
}
.front {
  z-index: 500;
  top: 150px;
  width: 6000px;
}
.intro {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/3woqwh2.png') no-repeat right 5px;
}
.page {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 1px #eee solid;

}
.panel1 {
  left: 1500px;
}
.panel2 {
  left: 2575px;
}
.panel3 {
  left: 3800px;
}
.panel4 {
  left: 5100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/css/jInvertScroll.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/js/jquery.jInvertScroll.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <div class="horizon scroll">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IImTBHM.png" alt="Background" />
  </div>

  <div class="middle scroll">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/e2pwKbv.png" alt="Clouds and Baloons" />
  </div>

  <div class="front scroll">
    <h1 class="intro">Scroll down</h1>

    <div class="panel1 page">
      <h2>The Hot Air Balloon</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="panel2 page">
      <h2>How they work</h2> 

    </div>

    <div class="panel3 page">
      <h2>Practicalities</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="panel4 page">
      <h2>Section 4</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```